# InstallationManager Class in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In my windows phone 8 application, i am looking for something which checks that either particular app is installed in phone or not. 
on msdn i found this, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/dn653756.aspx

but they have not given an example for how to use it, 
i tried in my app but it is giving error.

```
if(Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackages("","");)
{   
     //some action if app found installed. 
}
```

it gives me error that "No overload for method 'FindPackages' takes 2 arguments"

i cannot figure out what should i do. 
need help on this and if there is any other way to accomplish the task which i am looking for then please mention it.

Comment: Did you notice the referenced article states: _Minimum supported phone: Windows Phone 8.1_? Either your app is targeting the wrong version of WP or your question is tagged wrong.

Comment: yes, i got it. the previous error is gone, 
but now problem is with its return type, 
this api has package return type and i don't know how to deal with it . 
if you know then please share

Answer (score 1):

The package class provides details for a package. The return value that you get out of

```
var iIterable = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.findPackages(packageName, packagePublisher);
```

Is a : `IIterable<Package>`.

You can find information about the Package class here : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.package.aspx